# Add font in the browserleaks.com\fonts in the chromium browser code

Tags: c++, fonts, chromium, font-face, font-family

I am working on the Chromium browser codebase and aiming to dynamically add custom fonts to the font metrics section on browserleaks.com/font. Although I've tried installing the font manually by downloading the .ttf file, I now want to add the font programmatically by modifying the browser's source code.

My question is about pinpointing the specific file in the Chromium source code where modifications are required to add custom fonts dynamically. I'm seeking guidance on the necessary steps, including identifying the code responsible for font loading and rendering. Additionally, I'm interested in integrating with the font metrics feature.

Despite attempting manual installation, I prefer a dynamic approach and would appreciate assistance in locating the file or code snippet in the Chromium browser where I can make the necessary modifications to include custom fonts dynamically.

Comment: Chromium uses `Skia` for rendering: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/skia/ So it's most likely `Skia` you should be looking at.

Comment: Also Chromium interacts with `Skia` from here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:skia/

Comment: i want to install the fonts in the https://browserleaks.com/fonts in the Report field can you tell me about that how i add the font install  in the browser not the system